# BootStrap 3 Alignment of controls

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to align TextBox which will be used as Searchbox and button.

Problem is when I use inline form class on div the textbox is loosing its width.

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
             <input type="text" id="test" name="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E.g. Manchester">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group ">
                    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E.g. Manchester">
                    <input type="button" value="Search" class="form-control btn-lg"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

what I'm missing here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good solution for you:

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="E.g. Manchester" />
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E.g. Manchester" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

**Result:**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/j9EdZ/
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be best using the col-md-* values here, e.g.:

```
<div class='col-lg-6'>
    <form class='form'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='form-group'>
        <div class='col-md-10'>
            <input class='form-control input-lg' type='text' placeholder='E.g. Manchester'>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-2'>
            <input type='button' class='form-control btn btn-block' value='Search'>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Text-box is not loosing its width you can check here.

```
CODE : http://jsfiddle.net/Jaysinh/awYm3/
```

As per the Bootstrap documentation of Form you have to set the width of the element. Default is 100 % wide.

> Requires custom widths
>   Inputs, selects, and textareas are 100% wide by default in Bootstrap. To use the inline form, you'll have to set a width on the form controls used within.

Answer (score 0):

Here, check this out.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3133/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="test" name="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E.g. Manchester" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group ">
                <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="E.g. Manchester" />
                <input type="button" value="Search" class=" btn btn-lg btn-default" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group "></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```